# RemoveDataRecord<TEntity>(int id) - dynamically set TEntity

Tags: c#, reflection

```
var repo = new MyRepo();
repo.RemoveDataRecord<MyProj.Data.Person>(5);
```

The above removes a record from the Person table in my linq to sql repository.

This is what I'd like to do:

```
var repo = new MyRepo();
repo.RemoveDataRecord<"MyProj.Data.OrderItem">(17);
```

Purpose: each admin page has a table of records, and each record has a "delete" link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" id="17" type="MyProj.Data.OrderItem">delete</a>
```

So I can grab the id and the type of item to delete.

Is this possible?  Something like repo.RemoveDataRecord<"MyProj.Data.OrderItem">(17); ?  I'm assuming I need reflection.  Thanks!

Comment: ps. I've tried to do ... Type t = Type.GetType("MyProj.Data.OrderItem" ... then ... repo.RemoveDataRecord<t>(17), but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

First, let's get type reflection of your entity type:

```
var targetEntityType = Type.GetType("MyProj.Data.OrderItem");
```

Then, we need a reflection of generic RemoveDataRecord method definition

```
MethodInfo genericMethodDefinition = typeof(MyRepo).GetMethod("RemoveDataRecord");
```

See here, how to do this in refacrable way: [Is there a C# equivalent of typeof for properties/methods/members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478714/is-there-a-c-sharp-equivalent-of-typeof-for-properties-methods-members/8094901#8094901)

And now, each time you have to call this method, you should:
Get reflection of generic method, based on generic method definition:

```
MethodInfo genericMethod = genericMethodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(targetEntityType);
```

And invoke it:

```
genericMethod.Invoke(repo, new object[] { 17 });
```

Comment: This is awesome! Q: when I do Type.GetType("MyProject.Data.OrderItem"), I get a null value for that. OrderItem is a link 2 sql class. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hm.... try get assembly reftection first, for example: `var asm = typeof(OrderItem).Assembly;` Then get all types from this assembly, and filter them by name: `var entityType = asm.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Fullname == "MyProject.Data.OrderItem");`. I'm not sure, but also should work something like: `var entityType = asm.GetType("MyProject.Data.OrderItem");`

Comment: Also, there should be still possible to use Type.GetType(string) method, but in this case, you should use "assembly specified name" - google it to find format of string.

Comment: good idea. although, I'm trying to keep "MyProject.Data.OrderItem" a variable, so I can have this be a generic controller.  it'd be great if I could do, var asm = typeof("MyProject.Data.OrderItem").Assembly ...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, `typeof(MyProject.Data.OrderItem).Assembly` - is just to get Assembly reference, you don't need to get it for each of your entity type. Just once, Assembly property of Type class is the one of ways to get assembly reflection. you also can get asm reflection via `Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(<Full assembly name>)`

So, `var asm = typeof(OrderItem).Assembly` in my fisrt comment should be read as: `var asm = typeof(Your.DataAccess.Assembly.RandomEntityType).Assembly`

Comment: thanks Mavrinsky. my issue is, I don't know if it will be "MyProject.Data.Person" or "MyProject.Data.Order".  Is there a way to do typeof(string)? so this can be flexible? my route looks like this: "public ActionResult RemoveDataRecord(int id, string typeName)"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4979/discussion-between-ian-davis-and-mavrinsky)