# Dynamically Set TEntity Name to DbContext.Set

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am new to C# and Entity Framework. I have a scenario where I want to Insert Record to a Table based on Some Check and Conditions.

The problem is I do not know What Entity would be used to perform Insert/Update operation.

As you can see in Following C# Code I can Add UserLogs and PageLogs Entities in my Repository (Unit Of Work).

```
await _dbContext.Set<UserLogs>().AddAsync((UserLogs)ObjectChanges);

await _dbContext.Set<PageLogs>().AddAsync((PageLogs)ObjectChanges);
```

But in my Scenario, I only have String Names of Entities ("UserLogs", "PageLogs") and I can not Assign String Variable to `_dbContext.Set<>`

I tried to Get TEntityType by using

```
var TEntity = _dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .First(x => x.Name.Contains("UserLogs"));
```

I also have Tried to follow solution given to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099050/removedatarecordtentityint-id-dynamically-set-tentity).

But this also does not work, so I would like to know if there is any solution to this problem where I can DbSet a Dynamic Entity based on String Name.

**Code Update**

```
Type LogType = Type.GetType($"UserLogs");
            if (LogType != null)
            {
                var LogObject = Activator.CreateInstance(LogType);
                if (LogObject != null)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyInfo property in LogType.GetProperties())
                    {
                        if (property.CanWrite)
                        {
                            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                            {
                                property.SetValue(LogObject, Convert.ToString(Entity.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name)?.GetValue(Entity)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    var TEntity = _dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes().First(x => x.Name.Contains("UserLogs"));

                    await _dbContext.Set<$"UserLogs">().AddAsync(($"UserLogs")LogObject);
                }
            }
```

Comment: _"But this also does not work"_ - how exactly it does not work? Please share some code, ideally [mre] so others can copy-paste it and run.

Comment: Why do you want to go against the flow and go strings all the way? Where does your data come from that you don't know which entity you're working with? How does the `ObjectChanges` get instantiated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core : get list from dynamic table with string as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76196456/entity-framework-core-get-list-from-dynamic-table-with-string-as-parameter)

Comment: What are you trying to do? EF Core is an ORM, not a database driver. Like all ORMs, its job is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of table rows. How would your code work if you only had the *names* of the classes instead of the classes themselves?

Comment: As for `in my Repository (Unit Of Work).` that's your DbContext. A DbContext is *already* a Unit-of-Work and higher-level multi-entity repository. The DbSet is the single-entity repository. There are no CRUD methods like those found in low-level Data Access Objects because EF Core is an ORM, a higher-level abstraction that hides the CRUD details

Comment: I strongly suggest reading [Repositories and Unit-of-Work don't mix](https://robconery.com/databases/repositories-on-top-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/). There are a lot of articles, blog posts, SO answers about what you seem to be doing but Rob Connery's article is more entertaining

Comment: @CodeCaster I want to Save Audit Trails in Relevant Logs Table, i.e. If there is a Table called "User" & it has Logs enabled, then Any Row Changes in "User" Table will also be inserted into "UserLogs" table. So, if a Data is being Inserted/Updated in "User" table I want to dynamically Add its copy in "UserLogs" I've already managed to Copy Data From "User" to "UserLog" using Reflection but I am stuck at _dbContext.Set

Comment: @GuruStron I've updated my Question with my Complete Method where I am trying to Achieve Audit Trails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core has no non generic `DbSet` class. But it does not need to, since the `DbContext` class provides non generic equivalents of all generic `DbSet<T>` methods (except for querying).

For instance, [`Add(Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.add?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-add(system-object)):

> ```cs
> public virtual EntityEntry Add(object entity);
> ```

Similar for `AddAsync`, `Update{Async}`, `Remove{Async}` etc.

Internally it uses `GetType()` of the passed object to determine the entity type (thus table). So as soon as you can pass correct object instances (you need to do that anyway even with your original question), you can use these methods to perform the requested action.

e.g. with your example

```cs
await _dbContext.AddAsync((object)ObjectChanges);
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, but this couldn't help in my scenario. I've updated my Question with Complete Method Code, please have a look if you can understand and find any solution.

Comment: I don't see anything in your update which prevents the solution. The line `var TEntity = ...` is not needed, just remove it. And the last line becomes simply `await _dbContext.AddAsync(LogObject);`, exactly as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: You are right, It is now working without Casting, You are amazing Bundle of Thanks.